# dynamically access object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a variable type coming from an external react component called type.
I need to run certain logic according to type.
So if `type = foo` i want to run a command `x= user.foo.id` while if it is `boo` i want to run `x=user.boo.id`
I was thinking `x=user.${type}.id` but that is not working.
What is the best way of doing this without having to rewrite the whole code with an if statemenet for each type?